# steam distillation of 4-bromoaniline , why render it basic prior

Tags: acid-base, hydrolysis, distillation

In the multistage synthesis of 4-bromobenzenamine, why must the solution be rendered alkaline prior to the steam distillation after the hydrolysis of 4-bromo-*N*-ethanoylbenzenamine?

Comment: Which compound are you distilling, the 4-bromoaniline or the 4-bromo-N-ethanoylphenylamine?

Comment: the 4-ba might be a zwitterion and in the acidic medium it may be attracted to the cation forming a salt of whatever acid was used.This would raise the boiling point of the 4-ba enough to not come over to the receiving flask. When made basic with a reagent like naoh the sodium ion will react with the cation from the 4-ba salt and the 4-ba will be left as the free base which is more volatile and can be distilled .

Answer (score 5):

In principle, it is difficult to distill salts (ionic compounds). Therefore you first make sure that you have a free base in the solution. This is guaranteed in alkaline solution. For the steam distillation the compounds should be immiscible, which is another reason for having a free base. Let’s compare boiling points and solubility for aniline and its salt:

- Aniline b.p. 184 °C, solubility in water: 36 g/L
- Anilinium chloride b.p. 245 °C, solubility in water: 1070 g/L